# Prevent TypeScript from comparing to the wrong value in a list of possible types

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I'm creating some code that interfaces with a module and has several types that are more specific than the module allows, but are still fully compatible with the types the module specifies.

However, despite the compatibility, I'm getting this error:

> ```
>   Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
>     Type 'IDataPoint[]' is not assignable to type 'number[] | { x: any; y: any; }[] | [number, number][] | [number, number[]][]'.
>       Type 'IDataPoint[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
>         Type 'IDataPoint' is not assignable to type 'number'.
>           Type '[number, number]' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
> ```

The notable thing here is that the last line says "`Type '[number, number]' is not assignable to type 'number'`", even though `[number, number]` is is in the original list of allowable types. Why is it just comparing it to the first option and giving up? Is there any way I can get this to work without casting the value to the right type?

Comment: You need to show the code that's generating the error..

Comment: IDataPoint is a tuple of numbers and you are assigning it to something that should be a number.

Comment: You're likely misinterpreting the error.  The compiler doesn't "give up" when checking if `A` is assignable to `B | C | D`.  If `A` is not assignable to `B`, it will definitely *check* against `C` and `D`.  But if it turns out that it is not assignable to *any* of those, the displayed error might just talk about `B` to prevent such error messages from exploding into a combinatorial nightmare of all the ways in which `A` fails to be assignable to `B | C | D`

Comment: And yes, we need more information to tell you what's happening.  Please try to edit that code into a [mcve] that others can actually use to diagnose the issue.